# Вывести активный слайд в отдельный блок owl-carousel

Tags: javascript, html, css, owl-carousel

Как вывести активный слайд в отдельной блок где он будет отоброжаться и меняться при клике на слайде в превью. Использую owl-carousel 2.

Конечно есть вариант поставить другой слайдер, но он отпадает хотя бы потому что есть ещё более 5 слайдеров на сайте, как это сделать на js?

```js
$(".detail-slaider").owlCarousel({
  loop: true,
  margin: 10,
  nav: true,
  navText: false,
  responsive: {
    0: {
      items: 1
    },
    600: {
      items: 3
    },
    1000: {
      items: 3
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.carousel.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>

<div class="big-slaid">
  <div class="d-wrap">
    *здесь большой слайд*
  </div>
</div>

<div class="detail-slaider owl-carousel">
  <div><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt=""></div>
  <div><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt=""></div>
  <div><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt=""></div>
  <div><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt=""></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var onInitialized = function(e){
 var original = $($('.detail-slaider .active img')[0]).data('original');
 $('.big-slaid .d-wrap').empty().css({
  backgroundImage: 'url('+original+')'
 });
};
$(".detail-slaider").owlCarousel({
 loop: true,
 margin: 10,
 nav: true,
 navText: false,
 responsive: {
  0: {
   items: 1
  },
  600: {
   items: 3
  },
  1000: {
   items: 3
  }
 },
 onTranslated: onInitialized,
 onInitialized: onInitialized
});
$('.detail-slaider').on('click', 'img', function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
 var original = $(this).data('original');
 $('.big-slaid .d-wrap').empty().css({
  backgroundImage: 'url('+original+')'
 });
 return !1;
})
```

```css
.big-slaid .d-wrap {
 overflow: hidden;
 height: 0px;
 padding-bottom: 50%;
 background-repeat:norepeat;
 background-position: center center;
 background-size: cover;
 margin-bottom: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.carousel.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="big-slaid">
  <div class="d-wrap"></div>
</div>

<div class="detail-slaider owl-carousel">
  <div><img data-original="https://via.placeholder.com/500x214" src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt=""></div>
  <div><img data-original="https://via.placeholder.com/501x214" src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt=""></div>
  <div><img data-original="https://via.placeholder.com/502x214" src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt=""></div>
  <div><img data-original="https://via.placeholder.com/503x214" src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt=""></div>
</div>
```

Comment: thumb не соответствует слайду

Comment: @МаксимЛенский соответствует. Оригинальная картинка в `data-original` При клике - url берётся из неё. Если вам нужно из `src` - переделайте под себя. Всего одна строчка. При слайде берётся первый активный элемент, так как слайдов может быть 3 и 1 по условию.

Comment: ну как соответствует если на thumb одно изображение а в слайде другое ...вы сами посмотрите

Comment: Естественно. У всех thumb размер 350x150, а у оригинального 500x214. и далее, для примера, я увеличивал на единицу ширину оригинального изображения. PS: Чтобы было из src аттрибута. Замените везде `data('original')` на `attr('src')`